# 100% width to position fixed elements in fluid layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, position, fixed, fluid-layout

I am trying to create a fluid page layout with a fixed header. But I am having issues with making the fixed header fluid.

Here is the code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 68.5em;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1000px
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>
  </header>
</section>
```

Js Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/s2myn87q/4/

Answer (score 0):

Since most browsers use the following style in their default stylesheet:

```
body {
  margin: 8px;
}
```

You can use

```
header {
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: auto; /* default value */
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 8px;
}
.container {
  max-width: 68.5em;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1000px
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>
  </header>
</section>
```